# Why is this printing 0?

Tags: c++

Why is this printing 0? I swear I'm going crazy... Seriously.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    a + 1;
    cout << a << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, you have become crazy.

Comment: Agreed. I really have. I'm getting Old.

Comment: *warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a + 1;
```

You meant:

```
a = a + 1;
// or
a += 1;
```

The expression `a + 1` results in a value, but you have not assigned that value to anything (`a` in particular).